# JQuery nth Child divs children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I am using a div for each product list called `result-products` and within it are divs for title, image, description and info. The `result-products` will be called for every entry in the `database`. I want to get every third one to change to `result-products-third`. To do this i am using jquery code:

```
$("#products-results :nth-child(3n)").removeClass("result-products");
$("#products-results :nth-child(3n)").addClass("result-products-third");
```

`"#products-results"` is the containing div used.

The problem is when the nth child is getting every 3rd `"result-produts"` but it is also getting the third div inside that which is `"result-products-des"`.
How can i stop it going into the next child down

```
<div class="result-products">
  <div class="result-products-title">
    content
  </div>
  <div class="result-products-img">
    image
  </div>  
  <div class="result-products-des">
    description
  </div>
  <div class="result-products-info">
    info
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use child selector:

```
$("#products-results > :nth-child(3n)").removeClass("result-products");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function(){
            $(document).find('div').siblings().each(function(){
                var obj = $(this);
                obj.find('div').each(function(){
                    var obj1 = $(this);
                    if(!obj1.children().length > 0){
                        alert(obj1.html());
                    }
                });

            });
        });

<div id="2">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>XYZ Pvt. Ltd.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="3">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>ABC Pvt Ltd.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "$(function(){" first of fall, i have created anonymous function, which fired automatically. Inside that, i found three parent div using siblings. Then i iterated in all 3 parent div and check the length of every children length. How i can identify that whether is a last div or not in parent div. Now i am alerting the last div html of every 3 main parent div.